# php - find an image within a rectangle and crop out the contents of it

Tags: php, image-processing

I need to process the scanned images with php and crop a portion thereof which is located within a rectangle already drawn.
The rectangle is red, but since it is a scanned image, is difficult to define the hue. Unfortunately I do not know the library "gd2image" that well. Someone has already faced the same problem and wants to help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is untrivial. I would study [Opticrop](https://github.com/jueseph/Opticrop) as it already does what you wanted, only better :)

Comment: Thank for reply, you have an exanple for my case?

Comment: Did you try simply running `opticrop()` ? The algorithm is quite crafty and I bet it would find a rectangle like that.